# Is having a service that returns an object instead of using DI an Angular antipattern?

Tags: angularjs, anti-patterns, angularjs-injector

I have a situation at work where a developer created an angular service that returns a hook to an object that then is used to create an instance. Something like this...

```
var Item;
Item = function($q) {
  return Item = (function() {
    function Item(data) {
       ....
    }
  })
}
```

Then in the controller...

```
 function ItemImport($q){
     this.myItem = new this.Item(data);
 }
```

This so this is using a singleton to exclusively create an instance which seems wrong to me. I would think something like this would be better...

```
 function ItemImport($q, Item){
     this.data = {}
     Item.data = this.data
 }
```

Is this an anti-pattern? Or is it just an alternative way to create a service?